# KnockoutJS selecting nested lists like windows explorer

Tags: knockout.js

I have searched High and low for an answer to the following.

I have a list of folders and I want to be able to click on the folder and show its children.

This [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7zWfZ/) will explain it better, its nearly complete but it expands all folders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this happens because you are cycling all 'links' in 'selectedFolder' for every folder, not only the selected one!

this also means that the links are on BOTH folders "link1" and "link2", if you select "Folder1" OR "link3" and "link4" if you select "Folder2"!

you need to check that the current folder is selected before showing the links, something like:

http://jsfiddle.net/saurus/kJYsm/

note how I changed your

```
"with: $parent.selectedFolder"
```

with an

```
"if: $parent.selectedFolder().folderName == folderName"
```

and I have also added another div checking that "$parent.selectedFolder" is not undefined, without it a error occurs on first run. you can do on other ways: you can simply set 'selectedFolder' to a default dummy folder, or you can use  templating comments if you don't want the extra markup.

Note also that even removing the "with:" everything works, because now "$data" is the current folder, and this is exactly what we need.

hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Saurus thanks for this solution. Just one more question, how do I click an opened folder to close it?

Comment: see this forked version of the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/saurus/a3bjU/. I simply created an function (called 'SelUnsel') and bound it to 'click'. this function checks if the clicked element is the same already selected, sets the 'selectedFolder' to null, else sets the element clicked.